# [ROS2] Will all nodes implemented on_parameter_event be notified if set_parameters is called?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we do `ros2 set param <node> <param> <value>`, they will all be notified. How about if we create a parameter client and call `set_parameters(...)`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328583/%5Bros2%5D-will-all-nodes-implemented-on_parameter_event-be-notified-if-set_parameters-is-called?/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if I get the answer myself.

I was using AsyncParametersClient and all other nodes implement on_parameter_event are not notified.  I was also calling `set_parameters` in another thread so that's an issue.

But if I use SyncParametersClient, they are notified.

---

Originally posted by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) with karma: 112 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-07-15**:
Another thing is, only the node that is passed to the parameter client is notified. All other nodes are not. If we run `ros2 param set ...`, all other nodes are also notified.